# PyQT and QTreeView: Need to ask for childrens when user clicks on an item

Tags: request, pyqt, qtreeview

I need to create a QTreeView based on requests.

So, when the user open the application, it should make a request to get the root item for the tree. Once the user clicks on that item, it should ask for the children, and so on.

I couldn't find any working example with requests as I want and I don't even know if this is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple really.

Firstly, connect the tree's [expanded](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtreeview.html#expanded) signal to a handler, and populate the tree with the root's top-level items.

When the signal is fired, it will pass the index of the expanded item to the handler. The handler can then use this to check whether the item has any children using, say, the model's [hasChildren](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#hasChildren) method.

If the item already has children, do nothing; otherwise, populate it with whatever top-level items are appropriate for that item.

**UPDATE**

Below is a script demonstrates how to build a tree dynamically.

For simplicity, the demo uses a [QTreeWidget](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html), thus avoiding the need for a separate model. Additional data is stored within the tree by using [QTreeWidgetItem.setData](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidgetitem.html#setData).

Note that the `sip` import at the top is only needed for compatibilty between Python 2 and 3 (see [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/incompatible_apis.html#ref-incompat-apis) for details). If you're using Python 2, it's not needed.

```
import sip
sip.setapi('QVariant', 1)

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QTreeWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setHeaderHidden(True)
        self.itemExpanded.connect(self.handleExpanded)
        self.itemClicked.connect(self.handleClicked)
        self.handleExpanded(self.invisibleRootItem())

    def depth(self, item):
        depth = 0
        while item is not None:
            item = item.parent()
            depth += 1
        return depth

    def requestData(self):
        for title in 'One Two Three Four Five'.split():
            yield title, 'additional data'

    def addItems(self, parent):
        depth = self.depth(parent)
        for title, data in self.requestData():
            item = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(parent, [title])
            item.setData(0, QtCore.Qt.UserRole, data)
            if depth < 3:
                item.setChildIndicatorPolicy(
                    QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem.ShowIndicator)

    def handleExpanded(self, item):
        if item is not None and not item.childCount():
            self.addItems(item)

    def handleClicked(self, item, column):
        print(item.data(column, QtCore.Qt.UserRole).toPyObject())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand the part that I have to connect the signal to the handler, but not so well the part with the hasChildren method. When the expanded method is fired, should I then make the request to check if that item has childrens and then add them to the model? or should I create the model in another way?

Comment: @estemendoza. What is the data that is being used to populate the tree, and where does it come from?

Comment: The data is from a webservice, that given an item (father), it responds with the childrens of that item. Please, be patient with me because I'm new to PyQT and QT itself. Hope this helps.

Comment: @estemendoza. I have updated my answer with a simple demo, which should help to get you started.

Comment: Great, thanks for the example. I'll give a try and get back to you.

Comment: How do you think I can implement a "loading" every time the data is being loaded? Should I check if data is loaded, if not, create a child with a loading image or something like that?

Comment: @estemendoza. This is not simple to answer: it depends at lot on the nature of the data source. Please ask a new question with more details of what you are trying to do.